# Heatmap google map error with the array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I`m new with google maps y JS, and I have this problem.

this is my code:

```
var map, heatmap, data, position;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: makeRequest('jsonmapasenal.php', function(data) {

         data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
         data2 = [], range = data.length;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


             data2[i]= new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data[i].lat), parseFloat(data[i].lon));  ---------Here is the problem
        }


    console.log(data2);
    return data2;
    }),
    map: map
  });
}

function toggleHeatmap() {
  heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
}

function changeGradient() {
  var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ]
  heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
}

function changeRadius() {
  heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
}

function changeOpacity() {
  heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
}

 function makeRequest(url, callback) {
    var request;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5

    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(request);

        }
    }
   request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.send();


}
```

In the console the result is:

Uncaught Gc {message: "not an Array or MVCArray", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Gc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m… [_.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K, _.K]0: _.K1: _.K2: _.K3: _.K4: _.K5: _.K6: _.K7: _.K8: _.K9: _.K10: _.K11: _.K12: _.K13: _.K14: _.K15: _.K16: _.K17: _.K18: _.K19: _.K20: _.K21: _.K22: _.K23: _.K24: _.K25: _.K26: _.K27: _.K28: _.K29: _.K30: _.K31: _.K32: _.K33: _.K34: _.K35: _.K36: _.K37: _.K38: _.K39: _.K40: _.K41: _.K42: _.K43: _.K44: _.K45: _.K46: _.K47: _.K48: _.K49: _.K50: _.K51: _.K52: _.K53: _.K54: _.K55: _.K56: _.K57: _.K58: _.K59: _.K60: _.K61: _.K62: _.K63: _.K64: _.K65: _.K66: _.K67: _.K68: _.K69: _.K70: _.K71: _.K72: _.K73: _.K74: _.K75: _.K76: _.K77: _.K78: _.K79: _.K80: _.K81: _.K82: _.K83: _.K84: _.K85: _.K86: _.K87: _.K88: _.Klength: 89__proto__: Array[0]

If I include ' like this:

data2[i]= 'new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('+ data[i].lat +'), parseFloat('+ data[i].lon +'))';

works the array fill, but the console still throws the error: not an Array or MVCArray

please helpme!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what the problem is but I also had some problems when I started testing the Heatmaps. Here, I have a simple heatmap call, that I made a few weeks ago. Take a look at what I did on my HeatMap.
P.S: Try to be more specific on your problem next time...

```js
function myFunction {
  mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(some_lat, some_long),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: arrHeatmap // this array contains an x number of google.Maps.LatLng 
  });
  heatmap.setMap(map);
  console.log("Heatmap loaded successfully!");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I fix it! the problem was in the callback method, the position variable most be inside of the callback method! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, brother! Don't forget to check the answer, so we can help other people :)